# Cordova localStorage remove item after app close

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have an app with authentication.
After login I save user to local storage

```
localStorage.setItem('loggedUser', user);
```

and `localStorage.loggedUser` equals `some_mail@gmail.com`.
After closing the Cordova app and opening it again, `localStorage.loggedUser` equals `undefined`. Only this key (`loggedUser`) remains. Why does this happen?

Comment: can you share your code...

Comment: You probably accidentally overwrite the value of `localStorage.loggedUser` at some point.

Comment: what was the webview your using. Try updating the device webview. There was issues in chromium 138 , and they have fixed. try upgrading chromium webview in device.